# Adding single quotes to a string in Scala

Tags: string, scala, scala-collections

we are trying to add single quotes to each element of a set of string's in Scala

```
val s : Set[String] = Set("abcd","cdef")
```

Expected outcome is val s : Set[String] = Set("'abcd'","'cdef'")

tried multiple approaches 
Approach1:

```
s.map(x => x.mkString("'", "', '", "'"))
```

Approach2:

```
s.map(x => '\'' + x + '\'')
```

Fairly new to Scala if someone could please point us in the right direction it would be of great help

Comment: approach2 should work `s.map(x => '\'' + x + '\'')` or use multiline String `s.map(x => s"""'$x'""")` so that you dont have to escape. Try it on REPL

Comment: Approach1 works, you just have to choose the right middle element: `s.map(_.mkString("'","","'"))`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is no big difference between Scala and whichever language you've been using.
One thing you might want to use is [String interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)
and then you can write

```
s.map(x => s"'$x'")
```

Answer (score -1):

you cannot similar similar pattern to wrap it with double quotes. So, when it comes to single or double quotes wrapping, go for hex values. hex 22 is for double quotes and hex 27 for single quotes. It will be easy to remember.

```
scala> val sq = Integer.parseInt("27",16).toChar
sq: Char = '

scala> val dq = Integer.parseInt("22",16).toChar
dq: Char = "

scala>  val s : Set[String] = Set("abcd","cdef")
s: Set[String] = Set(abcd, cdef)

scala> s.map(x => s"$sq$x$sq")
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set('abcd', 'cdef')

scala> s.map(x => s"$dq$x$dq")
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set("abcd", "cdef")
```

hope, this adds clarity to such scenarios.